# Trying to get the value of a text box

Tags: c#, sql

I'm creating a sql statement in c#, and I am trying to get the value from a text box in a previous form:

```
SqlParameter PeriodFrom = new SqlParameter("@PeriodFrom", SqlDbType.VarChar);
PeriodFrom.Value =
```

I am just unsure of what goes after the equals sign. I tried the form `name.textbox name`.

Comment: Did you try formName.textBoxName.Text;

Comment: yes it didn work due to its protection level :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code behind of the form, inside the form class, you can declare a property:

```
public string TextBoxValue
{
    get
    {
        return textBoxName.Text;
    }
}
```

And you can use it with your SqlParameter like this:

```
    SqlParameter PeriodFrom = new SqlParameter("@PeriodFrom", SqlDbType.VarChar);
```

> <strike>PeriodFrom.Value = FormClassName.TextBoxValue;</strike>

Edit:

This wouldn't work since the Form class object is not static and it wouldn't persist. To make this work, you would need to make changes to the Program class. You would need to add a static Data member in the Program class like this:

```
public static FormClassName form;
```

and would need to pass this in the main method as below:

```
form = new FormClassName();
Application.Run(form);
```

And in the SQLParameter you can pass it like this:

```
SqlParameter PeriodFrom = new SqlParameter("@PeriodFrom", SqlDbType.VarChar);
PeriodFrom.Value = Program.form.TextBoxValue;
```

I tried to give you one of the ways to get the value but I do not think this is a good practice. Ideally, for passing values between forms, or layers you need to have some mechanism for storing and retrieving values, like a context, or Session. This is not the solution but a work around. And I take no responsibility if the code gets messed up cause of the above changes. :)

Comment: @CHRISTOPHER MCCONVILLE - If this helped you, you can upvote this too. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
YourPreviousForm.YourTextBox.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of textbox by using `Text` property of `TextBox`.

```
 PeriodFrom.Value =PrevForm.TextBox.Text;
```

As you are saying that there is no accessbile due to protection level, you need to work on the access modifier of form from `protected` to `public` so that it can be accessible.

Comment: im geting an error now, its inaccessible due to its protection level

Answer (score 0):

If your TextBox is publicly declared on your form, then you will be able to access its properties from the scope with which it was created in.

```
PeriodFrom.Value = otherForm.TextBoxName.Text;
```

If the 'previous' form object is not available to you now, then you will have to retrieve the value and pass it in as a parameter into your new form (or something of the sorts).  Please supply more code/details if you want help here.

Comment: you are correct davenewza, im getting an error now when i run it, say textbox is inacessible due to its protection level

Comment: You need to go into the design view of your form, find the control  and then change its Modifiers property from private/protected to public/internal.

Comment: Please note that this solution isn't great from a design perspective as it will lead to tight coupling.  You should consider rather exposing a custom property from your form which returns the appropriate value (as opposed to exposing the actual textbox).

Answer (score 0):

Change your textbox's modifier property to Public
then

formname.textboxname.Text

Comment: changing them to public does not help :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/SourcePage.aspx" %> 


if(PreviousPage != null)
{
    if(PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack == true)
    {
            PeriodFrom.Value =PrevForm.TextBox.Text;
    }
}
else
{
    PeriodFrom.Value = "Not a cross-page post.";
}
```